# Windows 8 : how to enable "net rpc shutdown"

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, samba

I'm a student and have a few servers/clients at home. One of those computers is running on Windows 8.
On this network, I have an embedded system on Debian that I use for VPN and SMB purposes. I has already scripts that do some wakeOnLan.

I've found recently that I can shutdown computers with Samba, using the command `net rpc shutdown`.

However, when I do it, i get an error:

> could not initialise pipe \winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

I've found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-mapping-to-hostnamec-share-on-windows-vista/) that a local user was, by default, not allowed to perform a shutdown remotely.

I've searched into the register the key to edit,  but I couldn't find it. It's at another place.

So, do you know how I can enable this "shutdown on LAN"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `\winreg` might mean that the `RemoteRegistry` service is not running; try using the following commands in Windows:

```
sc config RemoteRegistry start= auto
sc start RemoteRegistry
```

Comment: Thank you. There was a other thing to do : my local account, which was in the "Admin group" was not allowed to shutdown remotely. To do it, I needed to activate the user "Administrator"

Comment: @patxy: If your Windows version has `secpol.msc` or `gpedit.msc`, you can change it there.

Comment: Do not activate the user Administrator, just right click the cmd and open it as administrator. This worked for me.